# Unique solution of the Cauchy problem in the neighbourhood of the given set $\Gamma$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

The Cauchy problem $ \begin{cases}y\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0 \\
u=g  \;on \;\Gamma \end{cases}$

has a unique solution in a neighbourhood of $\Gamma$ for every differentiable function $g:\Gamma \to R\; if \\ 1. \Gamma =\{(x,0):x\gt 0\} \\ 2. \Gamma =\{(x,y):x^2 +y^2=1\} \\3.\Gamma =\{(x,y):x+y=1,x\gt 1\}\\4. \Gamma =\{(x,y):y=x^2,x\gt 0\}$

My Attempt: I solved the pde by taking $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-x}=\frac{du}{0}\\ u(x,y)=F(x^2+y^2)$

I don't know how to check the uniqueness in the neighbourhood of the given set. Thanks

Comment: Are your sets $\Gamma$ correct? I guess the $(x,0)$ should be $(x,y)$ for 2,3,4. Moreover, in case 2. the solution is not unique.

Comment: yes thanks. now i corrected it

Comment: @stb2084 how to check the uniqueness of the solution in the neighbourhood of $\Gamma$. i don't know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case 1. , you've derived
\begin{eqnarray}
g(x,0) = u(x,0) = F(x^2 + 0^2) = F(x^2).
\end{eqnarray}
Hence $F(w) = g(\sqrt{w})$ ($w>0$). Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
u(x,y) = F(x^2 + y^2) = g\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right). 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Then in case 2. g(x,y)=F(1). hence it do not have unique solution. What about case 4? I am not getting case 4.

Comment: For $r>0$ let $t(r)$ be the positive solution of the equation $t^2 + t^4 = r$ of $t$. Then $u(x,y) = g\left( t(x^2 + y^2), t(x^2 + y^2)^2 \right)$.